# DropDownListFor не выбирает значение с optionLabel

Tags: c#, mvc, razor

При выводе выпадающего списка с значением по умолчанию не отмечается текущее значение. Так всегда выбран 1 пункт "-- Способ оплаты --", хотя m.Filter.PayType заполнено:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Filter.PayType, f.PaymentTypesList, "-- Способ оплаты --", new { id = "payType", Name = "payType", @class = "select", style = "width:150px;" })
```

Если убрать значение по умолчанию, то отображение работает нормально:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Filter.PayType, f.PaymentTypesList, new { id = "payType", Name = "payType", @class = "select", style = "width:150px;" })
```

В чем может быть проблема? Мне все таки нужно значение по умолчанию.